# `:target` styles acting strange in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser-history, pseudo-class

I've written up some special styles for `div:target`. Chrome, Firefox and <del>IE9+</del>IE11 working nicely when I click `<a href="#target">`. Now I click the Back button (or "`javascript: history.go(-1)`") and **my URL bar immediately goes back**, but IE drags its feet going back to default styles, sometimes it takes 3-5 **seconds**, sometimes it doesn't update *at all* until I hit F12 and try to inspect the offending element (then it immediately updates). What gives?

**Update:** this seems to only happen in IE11. Everyone w/ (natively installed) IE9 has no problem. Even emulating IE9 with IE11 will have the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/r1rqp1sc/2/:

```js
$('#hello').click(function(){
    history.go(-1);
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background: gray; color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div:target { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#hello">Hello</a>
<div id="hello">Click here to go history:back()</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't answer the question, but it seems it has something to do with IE11 not redrawing efficiently after traversing history. Apparently just adding or removing a class on that element will force a redraw of that element.

```js
$('#hello').click(function(){
    history.go(-1);
    $(this).addClass('z').removeClass('z');
});
```